# Create Teradata SQLAlchemy Engine Using DSN

Tags: sqlalchemy, teradata

I am trying to make the switch from PYODBC to SQLAlchemy in order to connect to a Teradata database. However, I do not want to list all of the connection elements in my script. When using PYODBC, I was able to connect using a DSN with something like this:

```
import pyodbc as db

dsn = 'DSN=TERAPRD2'
cnxn = db.connect(dsn)
```

This worked great for me because I have many different scripts that all use the same DSN. So, when it came time to update my password I would only have to update it in one place and then all of my scripts would be able to read the new password.

With SQLAlchemy, everything that I have read on create_engine says to list out all of the elements as such:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

eng = sa.create_engine('teradatasql://whomooz/?user=guest&password=please')
```

With this method, I'd have to go into all of my scripts and update my password individually.

Is there a way to use variables or something to get the login info from my DSN? How can I make it operate more like PYODBC?

Edit:
Ok, based on Fred's comment, I now have this:

```
import configparser
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

user = config.get('TERADATA','user')
passw = config.get('TERADATA','passw')
host = config.get('TERADATA','host')
port = config.get('TERADATA','port')


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradata://'+user+':'+passw+'@'+host+':'+port+'/')

cnxn = engine.connect()
```

But, when it gets to the cnxn it gives me this error: Additional keyword arguments are not accepted by this function/method.  The presence of **kw is for pep-484 typing purposes

Comment: Yes, the connection string can be a variable rather than a literal. So you can obtain values from some common configuration file and build a connection string.

Comment: But now you have changed the format of the string. Try `'teradatasql://'+host+'/?user='+user+'&password='+passw` or if you really need a custom port number then include `+':'+port` immediately after the hostname